# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars app.launch_new_instance()

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

I am applying Euler's method to solve a differential equation. This is my code:

```
def f(x, y):
    return ((x**(2))*y)/((x**(4)) + (y**(4)))

di = 0.01
I = 100

x = np.linspace(-I, I, int(I/di) + 1)
w = np.zeros(len(x))

x[0], w[0]
for i in range(1, len(w)):
    w[i] = w[i - 1] + f(x[i - 1], w[i - 1])*di

plt.plot(x, w, label='approximation' )
plt.xlabel("x") 
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

When I run the code I have this Warning:

> "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__main__.py:3:     RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars app.launch_new_instance()"

I would like to now how to solve it and make it work.

Answer (score 11):

Your code is running into **Divide by Zero Error**. Try this to convince yourself:

```
>>> def f(x, y):
...     return ((x**(2))*y)/((x**(4))+(y**(4)))
...
>>> I, di = 100, 0.01
>>> x = np.linspace(-I, I, int(I/di) + 1)
>>> w = np.zeros(len(x))
>>> i = len(x)//2 + 1
>>> i
5001
>>> f(x[i-1], w[i-1])
nan
```

It clearly emerges from the interactive session above that when `i` takes the value `5001` in the for loop, `f(x[i-1], w[i-1])` yields `nan`. There are several solutions to this issue. For instance, in order to avoid [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) values you could check whether the denominator of the fraction returned by `f()` is zero prior to perform the division. If it is, you should return a conventional value of your choice (for example `0`) instead of the result of the division. The following snippet implements such approach though a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
def f(x, y):
    return (0 if x==0 and y==0 else float(x**2*y)/(x**4 + y**4))
```

Alternatively, you could disable run time warnings (but if you do so you need to be aware of the **potential risks**) by including this code in your script:

```
import warnings

def f(x, y):
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter('ignore')        
        return ((x**(2))*y)/((x**(4)) + (y**(4)))
```

---

The proposed workarounds avoid the RuntimeWarning but don't get your code working as you expect. Indeed, the calculated solution `w` is a vector in which all the elements are zero. I guess the reason for your code not being working properly is that you missed to assign `w[0]` an **initial value** different to `0`.

For example, if you simply add this line just before the for loop:

```
w[0] = 0.5
```

you get this (apparently meaningful) curve rather than a flat plot.

[image: Plot of w(x)]

Hope this helps!