# Which packages are responsible for different output between Python2 and Python3 and how to fix this issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, output

I am trying to reproduce some data with a model function. I checked the output with both `Python2` and `Python3` and the results are significantly different. 
I did that within `Jupyter` and also with a `.py` source and the same happens. 
I get also the following warning:

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Could it be a precision a precision problem?

Thanks a lot!

```
def r_diff(en):
    return np.sqrt(4*D_0*pow(en,delta)*(pulsar_ch_age[i]-t_0)*conv_factor_yr_to_sec*(1 - pow( 1 - en/E_max[i], 1-delta))/((1-delta)*(en/E_max[i])))

def J_e(E):
    if E > E_max[i] or r_diff(E)<r_kpc[i]:
        return 0
    return (Q_0_GeV_ch[i] / (pow(pi,3/2) * pow(r_diff(E),3)) * pow(E,-gamma) * pow(1 - E/E_max[i],gamma-2) * np.exp( - E /((1-E/E_max[i]) * E_c) ) * np.exp( - pow( r[i]/r_diff(E) ,2)))*(c/4*pi)

j_E_e = [J_e(x) for x in E_e]

print j_E_e

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

Comment: Maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780787/runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-double-scalars-app-launch-new-insta

Comment: This line `return (Q_0_GeV_ch[i] / (pow(pi,3/2) * pow(r_diff(E),3)) * pow(E,-gamma) * pow(1 - E/E_max[i],gamma-2) * np.exp( - E /((1-E/E_max[i]) * E_c) ) * np.exp( - pow( r[i]/r_diff(E) ,2)))*(c/4*pi)` may mean something completely different in Python 3. In Python 2, `/` is an integer division operator when the operands are integers. In Python 3 it is always a floating-point division operator. Check all of the division expressions for the type of the operands. If you put `from __future__ import division` at the top of your Python 2 program you will get the Python 3 behaviour. That may help.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BoarGules, it helped and worked good! Sorry for the ignorant question, I am still learning.

Comment: That is pretty well the only Python 2/3 difference that will give a wrong answer. The others will nearly always give syntax or runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway I still get a runtime error when using emcee, even though (I think) I have excluded all the sources of divide-by-zero possibilities. Is there any way I could understand where the problem is when running emcee?