# How to control which formula to apply in a function depending on the current value of two pandas dataframe arguments?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a function f(a, b) that is taking two pandas dataframes to apply different formulas to the values like this:

```
def f(a, b):
   if a > 0 and b > 0:
      return a + b
   elif a > 0 and b < 0:
      return a - b
   elif a < 0 and b > 0:
      return a * b
   elif a < 0 and b < 0:
      return a / b
   else:
      print('bad')

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1]})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'b':[2, 2]})
f(dfa,dfb)
```

The issue here in particular is, that I'd need the current value that is processed in the function to branch, however, using the and operator leads to this below.

> "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"

and using & is leading to a

> "cannot compare [type] array with a scalar of type [bool]"

Edit:

Considering the answers, I starting to realize that my minimal example might not transport my intention very well.

```
def f(a, b):
  if a > 0 and b > 0:
    X = operationA()
  elif a > 0 and b < 0:
    X = operationB()
  elif a < 0 and b < 0:
    X = operationC()
  elif a < 0 and b < 0:
    X = operationD()
  else:
    print('bad')

  Y = operationY()
  return X, Y

# both dataframes are part of a training example label example = (a, b)
df_label_partA = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, -1, -1]})
df_label_partB = pd.DataFrame({'b':[1, -1, 1, -1]})
f(df_label_partA, df_label_partB)
```

the data frames can't be considered separately as each is part of a list of labels (basically a tuple split up into 2 lists)

Comment: Always share the entire error message. I **strongly recommend** reading the Pandas docs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: No
To clarify it for _you_: The issue is the comparison

Comment: Isn’t that what the two linked questions are about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
pd.concat([dfa,dfb], axis=1).apply(lambda x: f(*x), axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```py
0    3
1    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: how does the lambda call handle 2 return values? I've edited my question

Comment: _how does the lambda call handle 2 return values?_ It doesn't, the output is a Series, the leftmost numbers are the index.

Comment: So ```pd.concat``` will make both columns side by side adjacent. Then ```*x``` will just unpack them column-wise (hence ```axis=1``` in ```apply```).

Comment: Check for instance: ```pd.concat([dfa,dfb], axis=1).apply(lambda x: list([*x]), axis=1)``` - ```*``` in this case unpacks the values

Comment: Thank you, for your clarification. This approach appears to be very promising. My last issue is, however, that the call returns a list of tuples in the form `(x, y)` for each line. Do you happen to know how to convert it back into output variables, like `X, Y = concat(...)` or do you think a new thread would be good? Thank you again.

Comment: Hm, not sure, if I understand what you mean? You can always decompose it by referring to particular column i.e. if ```df=pd.concat(...)``` then ```x=df['a']``` and ```y=df['b']```

Comment: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKfYw.png) Here's a screenshot of the output. _r_ basically contains sort of a DataFrame with a single column and this column is containing a tupel of 4 values. I'd rather return series though for further use. Thank you for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok- this should work for you: ```a,b,c,d=verify(...)[...].apply(pd.Series).to_numpy().T```

Comment: Thank you. It sort of works now. I'm receiving an error, though at runtime: _D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:15: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app_ Didn't receive the message before adding `.apply(pd.Series).to_numpy().T`

Comment: It would be odd, assuming data hasn't changed in between, but maybe it's something around this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37784106/11610186

Comment: turns out, there was one single value in 160 000 that caused this issue. It's working now, although a bit slow. But it gets the job done. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
def f(a, b):
   if all(a > 0) and all(b > 0):
      return dfa.a + dfb.b
   elif all(a > 0) and all(b < 0):
      return dfa.a - dfb.b
   elif all(a < 0) and all(b > 0):
      return dfa.a * dfb.b
   elif all(a < 0) and all(b < 0):
      return dfa.a / dfb.b
   else:
      print('bad')

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1]})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'b':[2, 2]})
f(dfa,dfb)
```

---

output

```
0    3
1    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. If I understand all(..) correct it's true when all entries are meeting the condition. However, I definitely know that the values are either positive, negative, or 0, and a is linked to b so I need the values of the same index. a and b are of equal size, though. I edited my question